# How i can fill two different tableview in one viewcontroller in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if tableView == table1{
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! acntTableViewCell
        cell.account.text = account[indexPath.row].email
        return cell
    }
    else if tableView == table2 {
        let cell2 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell2")
            as! popTableViewCell

        cell2.pop.text = pop[indexPath.row].answer
        return cell2
    }
}//its give me  error here Missing return  in function
```

I am going to fill two different tables in one viewcontroller. when I return cell it give me error  Missing return in function where I am doing wrong can any one suggest me what's wrong with this code

Comment: You need to always return a cell from that function.  In your case you have 2 if statements, but if neither pass you need a fallback option.

Comment: @creeperspeak you should post that as the answer. As an aside, it's almost never the answer to have multiple table views on a single screen. Conflicting or confusing gestures. UITableView supports sections for this.

Comment: Just delete `if tableView == table2`. That solves the issue.

Comment: if i delete if tableview == table2  in this way both table view are going to populate because both tableview gona populate with different array -vadian?

Comment: No, if there are two table views and `tableView == table1` fails then logically it can only be `table2`. The `table1` branch got its own `return` statement

Answer (score 6):

In the first place, you should compare tables using `===` (references), not `==`.

This is one of the cases when an assertion failure is a good way to tell the compiler that no other way of the function exists e.g.:

```
if tableView === table1 {
    return ...
} else if tableView === table2 {
    return ...
} else {
    fatalError("Invalid table")
}
```

You can also use a `switch`:

```
switch tableView {
   case table1:
       return ...
   case table2:
       return ...
   default:
       fatalError("Invalid table")
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Both answers are correct, but I believe the best way to do it would be to separate each table view to have its own data source object, not a view controller. Putting multiple tableview data source protocols adds a decent amount of unnecessary code, and if you refactor them into separate objects, you can help avoid a Massive View Controller.

```
 class FirstTableViewDataSource : NSObject, UITableViewDataSource {

    var accounts: [ObjectTypeHere]

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return accounts.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! AcntTableViewCell
        cell.account.text = accounts[indexPath.row].email
        return cell
    }

}

class SecondTableViewDataSource : NSObject, UITableViewDataSource {

    var pops: [ObjectTypeHere]

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return pops.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! PopTableViewCell
        cell.account.text = pops[indexPath.row].answer
        return cell
    }
}
```

From there, just update the tableviews to pull from these objects

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.table1.dataSource = FirstTableViewDataSource()
    self.table2.dataSource = SecondTableViewDataSource()
}
```

Comment: Then what you prefer a suitable way to do it with an example if you provide ?

Comment: thanks provding a example i ll try it and then give you feed back about this Matthew knippen

Comment: if you could provide full filde code so i can remove error in it

Comment: Could you be more specific as to what kind of error you're receiving?

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is analyzing what will happen if `tableView` is neither `table1` nor `table2`.  If that should happen, the function will exit with nothing to return.

That's an error.

Answer (score 0):

Your `cellForRowAt` method should always return a cell, so

**Try this way**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if tableView == table1{
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! acntTableViewCell
        cell.account.text = account[indexPath.row].email
        return cell
    }
     //if tableView is not table1 then
    let cell2 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell2")
            as! popTableViewCell

     cell2.pop.text = pop[indexPath.row].answer
     return cell2
}
```

Comment: in this way does it populate both tableviews ? Reinier Melian

Comment: Thanks all of you now i got the problem :)

Comment: yes i have Already accept it but it kept on saying with notification vote with less then 15 reputation are Recorded but do not change Publicly they record your answer but not publicly

Answer (score 0):

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var table1: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var table2: UITableView!
let firstClassRef = FirstTableView()
let secondClassRef = SecondTableView()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

   firstClassRef.array1 = ["1","2","3"]
    secondClassRef.array2 = ["1","2","3","1","2","3"]

    self.table1.dataSource = firstClassRef
    self.table2.dataSource = secondClassRef

    self.table1.delegate = firstClassRef
    self.table2.delegate = secondClassRef

    self.table1.reloadData()
    self.table2.reloadData()
 }
}

class FirstTableView: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
var array1 = Array<Any>()

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return array1.count
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell1", for: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
    cell.textLabel?.text = array1[indexPath.row] as? String
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
    return cell
}
}

class SecondTableView: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
var array2 = Array<Any>()

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return array2.count
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell2", for: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
    cell.textLabel?.text = array2[indexPath.row] as? String
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
    return cell
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use Switch Statement**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController , UITableViewDelegate , UITableViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet weak var topTableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var downTableview: UITableView!
    var topData : [String] = []
    var downData = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        topTableView.delegate = self
        downTableview.delegate = self
        topTableView.dataSource = self
        downTableview.dataSource = self

        for index in 0...20 {
            topData.append("Top Table Row \(index)")
        }

        for index in 10...45 {
            downData.append("Down Table Row \(index)")
        }

    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        var numberOfRow = 1
        switch tableView {
        case topTableView:
            numberOfRow = topData.count
        case downTableview:
            numberOfRow = downData.count
        default:
            print("Some things Wrong!!")
        }
        return numberOfRow
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell = UITableViewCell()
        switch tableView {
        case topTableView:
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "topCell", for: indexPath)
            cell.textLabel?.text = topData[indexPath.row]
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        case downTableview:
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "downCell", for: indexPath)
            cell.textLabel?.text = downData[indexPath.row]
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
        default:
            print("Some things Wrong!!")
        }
        return cell
    }
}
```